# Priorizar palavras chaves encontradas no titulo na busca sql

Tags: php, sql, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá, possuo uma tabela 'videos' com 3 campos 'nome', 'descricao' e 'categorias'. Ao fazer uma busca quero que apareça no topo os videos que no 'nome' tenham mais dessas palavras chaves, por exemplo se eu pesquiso "casa bonita" um vídeo com nome 'CASA em alagoas BONITA' tem que ficar mais no topo que um video com nome "sao paulo CASA" e descricao "olhe como ela é BONITA"(pois faço a pesquisa procurando as palavras chaves em nome e descricao).

Alguem tem uma idéia de como fazer isso?

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/490708-consulta-por-relevancia-mysql/?do=findComment&comment=1950568   algo assim , mas existem soluções melhores.

Comment: @AlvaroPacíficoSerpa Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? (Oracle Database, mariaDB, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL etc)

Answer (score 0):

Esse assunto pode ser bem mais complexo do que parece ser.. A busca relevante, por assim dizer.

Mas, respondendo mais diretamente a sua pergunta, eu sugeriria utilizar a cláusula UNION .

```
SELECT * (<condicoes com alta prioridade>)
UNION
SELECT * (<condicoes com um pouco menos de prioridades>)
UNION
SELECT * (<condicoes com menos de prioridades ainda>)
```

Ou, uma outra sugestão é utilizar uma variável de ranking

> SELECT t.*,  [expressao de ranking] AS ranking FROM () AS t ORDER BY
>   ranking DESC